Expansion of squared L2 norm
Found such expression in a handbook:
$$||Ax-y||_2^2=x^TA^TAx-2y^TAx-y^Ty$$
where $A \in R^{n\times n}$
Can't get why this expression holds?
I understand that it holds when there is no L2 -norm, as soon as it's just a square of the sum. But when the norm is involved, I do not get why it holds.
$$(Ax-y)^2=x^TA^TAx-2y^TAx-y^Ty$$

Are you sure it holds when there’s no norm? The right hand side of your second “equality” is a scalar.

What do you mean by $v^2$? Isn't it $v\cdot v$, i.e.$v^Tv$? And what makes you believe there is some L2 norm involved (hence some measure)? Doesn't $|v|_2$ here simply denote $\sqrt{v\cdot v}$?

@AnneBauval yes exactly that ⋅ . Expanding $(−)^2$ yields = $^^−2^−^$.
But I can't comprehend, why such expansion holds for squared L2 norm

Again: what makes you believe that your handbook is using any L2 norm? Doesn't its $|v|_2
$ simply denote  $\sqrt{v\cdot v}$? Please check where it introduces this notation.

$\sqrt{\vec{v}\vec{v}}$ denotes L2 norm, by definition isn't it?

Note that the bare square $v^2$ is a usual shortened notation for the squared 2-norm $\|v\|_2^2$ $-$ and not the $L^2$-norm, since you doesn't seem to deal with functional spaces and integral inner products, but to work in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then, the said relation can be proven thanks to the properties of the scalar product this norm, namely linearity and symmetry, as done below :
$$
\begin{align}
(Ax-y)^2 &= \|Ax-y\|_2^2 \\
         &= \langle Ax-y, Ax-y \rangle_2 \\
         &= \langle Ax,Ax \rangle_2 - \langle Ax,y \rangle_2 - \langle y,Ax \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle_2 \\
         &= (Ax)^TAx - 2\langle y,Ax \rangle_2 + y^Ty \\
         &= x^TA^TAx - 2y^TAx \color{red}{+} y^Ty
\end{align}
$$

I see, thank you
